# Pyglet and PIL: glError

Tags: python, 3d, python-imaging-library, pyglet

I am wondering why I can get this error:

```
pyglet.lib.gl.GLExeption: invalid value
at: self.group = TextureGroup(image.load(TEXTURE_PATH).get_texture())
```

Imported libs:

```
import sys
import math
import random
import time
from collections import deque
from pyglet import image
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.graphics import TextureGroup
from pyglet.window import key, mouse, Window
from PIL import Image
```

I'm using PIL for making the PNG:

```
print "Creating ", TEXTURE_PATH
images = map(Image.open, texture_path)
widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

total_width = sum(widths)
max_height = max(heights)

new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

x_offset = 0
for im in images:
    new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
    x_offset += im.size[0]
new_im.convert('RGB')
new_im.save(TEXTURE_PATH, "PNG")
```

And the 'texture_path`(lowercase) is here:

```
texture_path = ['res/textures/grass_top.png'] * 99
```

The full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythoncode\pyglet\minecraft_remake.py", line 955, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\pythoncode\pyglet\minecraft_remake.py", line 948, in main
    window = Window(width = 640, height = 480, caption="Minecraft 3d!", resizable=True)
  File "D:\pythoncode\pyglet\minecraft_remake.py", line 554, in __init__
    self.model = Model()
  File "D:\pythoncode\pyglet\minecraft_remake.py", line 198, in __init__
    self.group = TextureGroup(image.load(TEXTURE_PATH).get_texture())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\__init__.py", line 818, in get_texture
    force_rectangle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\__init__.py", line 803, in create_texture
    rectangle, force_rectangle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\image\__init__.py", line 1514, in create
    blank)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\lib.py", line 104, in errcheck
    raise GLException(msg)
GLException: invalid value
```

I found the problem, but didn't know how to fix it, the problem are in the PNG making.

When I replace the textures.png with another picture, it's working
but when I make one with PIL, it doesn't work.

Comment: Where does Pyglet come into play?

Comment: at self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

Comment: Creating a batch() shouldn't cause any texture errors, could you perhaps paste in the relevant code and the full trace-back of the error (not just the two lines you think is relevant), cheers!

Comment: i've added more info about the error

Comment: It might be because you're not saving the alpha channel, you're just saving the `RGB` channel, could you try: `new_im.convert('RGBA')`?

Comment: tried that, but still return the same error

Comment: What does for instance, ImageMagick `identify -verbose image.png` say about both your non-working image and a working image?

Comment: print "importing icons"          .
item_icon = [pyglet.image.load('res\\textures\\grass_top.png')] * 99       . 
item_icon[0] = pyglet.image.load('res\\textures\\grass_side.png')      ;
item_icon[1] = pyglet.image.load('res\\textures\\brick.png')      ;
item_icon[2] = pyglet.image.load('res\\textures\\sand.png')      ;
item_icon[3] = pyglet.image.load('res\\textures\\bedrock.png')      ;
item_icon[4] = pyglet.image.load('res\\textures\\dirt.png')      ;
item_icons = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(item_icon[0], x=50, y=50)      ;
print "done"      ;

Comment: Still not the information I requested, I'm looking for the meta data. This is some sort of icon loading and sprite thing.. What's this comment about?

Comment: its loading the icons

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqejf2ygar6lpjg/code.txt?dl=0

Comment: I can't open dropbox links, so either use a service like https://gist.github.com/ or paste the code in a edit, otherwise I can't see the code.

Comment: Anyway i have found the solution. Im Greatly Appreciate your help Torxed :)

Comment: Don't forget to post your solution :)

Comment: Currently i dont have the link for it, i found it on myself, but i'll update the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: the problem is in my .PNG Editor, i just make the image manually and it works!

im using Graphics Gale Free edition to edit and it will work.

i think the problem is in the PIL itself. Or The pyglet doesnt load PIL config PNG

P.s it may be because color configuration